# How do I get rested XP?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

How do I get rested xp? Do I need to have a subscription?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Free to Play page](http://www.lotro.com/free.php) on the LOTRO site, rested XP is only available to VIP accounts, which require a current subscription.